# java.io.IOException while reading multiple file from FTP Client

Tags: java, apache-commons-net

I have the below method of *readFile*. I have a HashMap that contain filenames along with their timestamp.
Using *for* loop, I'm trying to read contents of all files in the HashMap.

```
    public static void readFile(String remoteFile, FTPClient ftp) throws Exception {
        InputStream iStream =ftp.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile);
        BufferedInputStream bInf = new BufferedInputStream(iStream);
        int bytesRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        String fileContent = null;
        while ((bytesRead = bInf.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fileContent = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        System.out.println(fileContent);
    }
```

Intention: Pass content of each file as byte[] to another application but facing below issue:

```
# Properties of srvDEVSchoolInfo

[srvDEVSchoolInfo]
IS_PAYLOAD_LOG_REQD = true
IS_VALIDATION_ENABLED = true
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at FileReadFTP.readFile(FileReadFTP.java:252)
    at FileReadFTP.getFileContentFromFTP(FileReadFTP.java:74)
    at FileReadFTP.main(FileReadFTP.java:37)
```

All the files (TOML) contain dummy data. What am I missing? Not an expert in java, any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Add try with resources or close the iStream explicitly after use, it may be related to this problem.

Comment: Hi @DuncG, when I try to read only 1 file (explicitly mentioning file name) it works fine however the problem exists when I do it dynamically in loop. Also tried explicitly closing the Input stream.. No luck 

Comment: You certainly need to close this stream. You need to post the calling code. NB Your read loop isn't valid. You will only display the content of the last buffer read, not the entire file: but you shouldn't be trying to load entire files into memory anyway.

Comment: Hi @Marquis, Actually what I'm trying to achieve is content of each file will be a message that's need to be pushed to IBM Message Broker. Sending message of each file as spitted message will add complexity which I'm trying to ignore. Can you please suggest me an alternative if u have any in mind?

Comment: Actually you need to do what I said: close the stream and post the calling code. Until you fix the obvious error and provide enough information for a diagnosis it is beyond absurd to expect a suggestion for an alternaitve: when we don't even know what you need an alternative to, or why.

Comment: Hi @MarquisofLorne Thanks a lot, your suggestion worked! I added ```iStream .close();``` and ```ftp.completePendingCommand();```

Comment: Here's a [link](https://programmer.group/ftpclient-reads-files-continuously.html) that helped me as well!